# Reference Types Copying and Garbage Collector

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, reference-type

I have the following function:

```
HashSet<string> Func()
{
     HashSet<string> output = new HashSet<string>();
     output.Add("string_1");
     output.Add("string_2");
     return output;
}
```

Then I call this method and copy it to a reference type:

```
HashSet<string> bindingObjct = Func();
```

This is reference copying from the return of the function "output" and the binding variable at call "bindingObjct", so both are referring to the same objects.

My question:
When garbage collector is made on "output" (the local variable inside the function), will this affects "bindingObject"? even  while using "bindingObject" recently?

Answer (score 4):

Garbage collection is performed on objects, not on variables. `output` is not garbage collected; the `HashSet` you created (which had a reference temporarily stored in `output`) will be garbage collected at some point after no live variables store references to it.

In short, the variables you're referring to will not be changed in any way. The `HashSet` remains valid for its lifetime. Once it's eligible for garbage collection you will no longer be able to access it (by definition; if you were able to access it, it wouldn't be eligible for garbage collection).

Comment: Exactly. The *value* of the local variable `output` is a *reference* and lives on the call stack (or maybe in a CPU register, who knows?). When the method has returned, that value (reference) on the stack will be popped. The garbage collector is not involved here. The garbage collector will look at the *object* created with `new HashSet<string>()` once in a while and determine if anything still refers to that object. Even when value `output` no longer exists, `bindingObjct` may still exist as a reference, and in that case the `new HashSet<string>()` is still alive, and GC will not collect it.

Answer (score 1):

The GC will only collect objects that are no longer referenced anywhere - it's fairly pessimistic by default. If you have several references to the same object the .NET GC will handle this, but tracking the life of the object and graph can become a factor in performance.

So by my understanding the answer to your question is 'No', the GC will not act on an object that is referenced elsewhere